# Dynamically var in parameter of a function

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to call a function using a name of a var dynamically, but I don't know if this is possible, something like that:

```
fight_movies = list() # var how I want to use in function call
win_movies = list() # var how I want to use in function call
knowledge_movies = list() # var how I want to use in function call
biography_movies = list() # var how I want to use in function call

for genre in genres:
    .... Ommited #\/\/\/\/\/\/ Here is where I call the function
    write_jsonl(genre + '_movies', genre, rating, title, genre) #here is the call of the function


def write_jsonl(movie_list, genre, rating, title, json_name):
    dict = {'title': title, 'genre': genre, 'rating': rating}
    movie_list.append(dict)
    # print(action_movies)
    with jsonlines.open(json_name+'.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
        writer.write(movie_list)
```

I'm trying to pass the variable name as a list dynamically, but I'm not sure if that's possible in python, any suggestions?

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bucky.py", line 58, in <module>
    web_crawling()
  File "bucky.py", line 34, in web_crawling
    write_jsonl(genre + '_movies', genre, rating, title, genre)
  File "bucky.py", line 52, in write_jsonl
    movie_list.append(dict)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, you're right Filip Mlynarski, but I believe what he's trying to do is to pass this dynamically so he doesn't  have to keep calling the function multiple times and creating multiple ifs for each genre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a dictionary:

```
genres_dict = {k: [] for k in ('fight', 'win', 'knowledge', 'biography')}

for genre in genres:
    write_jsonl(genres_dict[genre], genre, rating, title, genre)
```

A variable number of variable is *not* the recommended approach.

Related: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables).

Answer (score 1):

You could find your variables in [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)/[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) like so

```
for genre in genres:
    #.... Ommited \/\/\/\/\/\/ Here is where I call the function
    write_jsonl(locals()[genre + '_movies'], genre, rating, title, genre) #here is the call of the function
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by most use a dictionary, and then if you want and I think what you are intending for it to do is to then store the dictionary in a list. However, your code shows a problem where you passed a string for what I believe you intend to be a list.

```
def write_jsonl(movie_list, genre, rating, title, json_name):
    d= {'title': title, 'genre': genre, 'rating': rating}
    movie_list.append(d) #<-- movie_list based on your traceback is a str
    # print(action_movies)
    with jsonlines.open(json_name+'.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
        writer.write(movie_list)
```

The example below works as intended:

```
all_movie_list = []

def write_jsonl(movie_list, genre, rating, title, json_name):
    d= {'title': title, 'genre': genre, 'rating': rating}
    movie_list.append(d)
    # print(action_movies)
    with jsonlines.open(json_name+'.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
        writer.write(movie_list)

write_jsonl(all_movie_list,'Crime','10','Godfather','test')

all_movie_list
[{'title': 'Godfather', 'genre': 'Crime', 'rating': '10'}]
```

The better way is to store your list of titles by genre in a dictionary, you can use the `defaultdict` data model from the Python standard library for that.

```
from collections import defaultdict
movie_list = defaultdict(list)

def write_jsonl(movie_list, genre, rating, title, json_name):
    d= {'title': title, 'genre': genre, 'rating': rating}
    movie_list['{}_movies'.format(genre)].append(d)
    # print(action_movies)
    with jsonlines.open(json_name+'.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
        writer.write(movie_list)

movie_list
>>defaultdict(list,
            {'Crime_movies': [{'title': 'Godfather',
               'genre': 'Crime',
               'rating': '10'}]})

movie_list['Crime_movies']
>>[{'title': 'Godfather', 'genre': 'Crime', 'rating': '10'}]
```

Also do not use inbuilt method or reserved names as variables, I replaced your `dict` variable to just `d`.